# EntityFramework Code-First Database Design

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, ef-code-first

I'm trying to sketch out a basic music catalog database using EF6 Code-First approach. That's what i've done so far:

We have **Bands**, which consist of **Artist**(s) and may have **Albums**.

**Album** contains **Song**(s) and may have **Cover**.

**Band** belongs to one or many **Genre**(s). **Compilation** is just a collection of some **Bands**

**Band** may have **Photo**(s). **Artist** may also have individual **Photo**(s).

Here is a diagram of what I've managed to achieve so far (generated from DbContext):

[image]

### Questions:

1. How can I implement many-to-many relationship between **Genre** and **Band** (multiple Bands belong to many Genres)?
2. How can I make **Band** belong to many **Compilations**?
3. Is my design flawed from the beginning? Any suggestions on improving (maybe even re-designing) it?

Feels like I'm missing pretty basic stuff here.

Thanks for taking your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. for the m:m relationship between Band and Genre you need one more table Band_Genre that has 2 fields, ID_Band and ID_Genre.
2. for the band-compilation relationship, you can do a bit different, add songs to the compilations (as in the real world) and then follow Band-Album-Song-Compilation relationship. Why is a compilation not an album?

Overall pretty sound design.

Comment: Thanks! **As of 1st**: I thought EF may handle it on it's own somehow. Well, old methods always get the job done :) **As of 2nd**: By compilations here I meant things like "Classic Heavy-Metal Bands". Not a good word for that, though. I think I'll reconsider that closer to your suggestion.

Comment: if you really do code-first EF will handle and it will create that extra table for the m:m relationship (look here for example: http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2012/06/13/many-to-many-relationships-with-ef.aspx).